# BL_Custom Grid extension

Tags: sales-order, custom-grid

my requirement is to add custom columns in `sales/order` grid in admin.
when i enabled path hints, it gave me the path `adminhtml\default\default\template\bl/customgrid/widget/grid/16.phtml`

so first of all i wanted to disable that module and see the output .

i disables it in `system/configuration/advanced`.

and cleared the cache, then logged out and again freshly logged in , but still its giving the same path .

how is it possible?

Comment: Please put more details otherwise question, going to closed

Comment: best way to disable extension is via .xml in `app/etc/modules` - then flush cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When enabled, the BL Custom Grid extension creates a `Grid Customization` button above the `Reset` and `Search` buttons on the right side of the grid.

Clicking this button will open an area that will let you customize the columns in that display.

[image]

Use the `More Options` button to view commonly used columns for that specific grid. <strike>Otherwise click `Add Attribute Column` to create a new row at the bottom of the list. Use the `Field Name` column drop down to change the related attribute information shown. Some attributes may require further `Configuration` via the link provided.</strike> There are also `Store View` dependent options, column name, and width settings to be adjusted if desired.

The customization of the Sales Order page is not as feature-rich as the product catalog is, so you may not find all of the options you are looking for. I've found a lot of what I need to show in the "Custom Columns" area and have been able to get by with filtering down from there.

Comment: Hi Steven , i can't see "Add Attribute Column" to create a new row , could you please let me know how to get that one ?

Comment: i can see there is blue color button (Add Attribute Column) in your screenshot, but i don't have that one, how can i get it, do i need to install any extension for that ?

Comment: I am using a custom admin theme that may change the appearance of the buttons. You should have the same layout, just not the same colors.

Comment: I realize I posted a screenshot of the manage catalog page, not the sales orders page. I have updated the screenshot to and removed the text for the "add attribute" button. The Sales Order page is limited to the options found in the "Custom Columns" area in "more options" - as shown in updated screenshot. If you want to add something outside of those selections, I am not sure this extension is the right choice for you.

Comment: @StevenJ how can i add a custom attribute in sales order grid. In managed Products grid we can easily add another custom attribute, but how can i add a custom attribute in sales order grid.

Comment: @zus the sales>orders page works a bit differently and limits the attributes you can reference (using this extension). Selecting `Grid Customization` will open a drawer, inside of that you should see `Custom Columns` which has a lot of options for customer info, item info, and sales totals.

Comment: @StevenJ How can i add my Custom Attribute on sales order grid, there is no option in "Custom Columns" for adding my own custom attribute.   my post : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/196004/57334

Comment: I need this extension for magento 2. Does anybody have it?